# Timestamp off by an hour during Daylight Transition when Migrating data to Sql server using AWS Database MIgration service

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, replication, sql-server-2019, dms

We are trying to migrate a MySQL database on AWS RDS to SQL Server Database on AWS.

Both the Source and Target Database are created in PST Time zone.

Replication Instance Version : 3.4.4
Mysql Version: 5.7
Sql server Edition : Standard edition 15.00

Source MYSQL database has the parameter time_zone = `US/Pacific` attached to the Cluster parameter group.

DMS extra connection attribute on the Source looks like below.

```
serverTimezone = US/Pacific
```

I have tried to migrate the data from Source to Target and found the below discrepancy.

On full load, during the daylight transition time the timestamp datatype variables were getting off by an hour for 10 hours.

Source:

```
id  Created_at
1   2021-07-13 18:01:48
**2 2019-11-02 18:23:00
2   2020-03-07 16:19:00
4   2020-10-31 17:01:00
5   2021-03-13 17:01:00**
6   2021-07-13 18:04:20
8   2021-07-13 18:09:46
```

Target:

```
id  Created_at
1   2021-07-13 18:01:48
**2 2019-11-02 17:23:00
2   2020-03-07 17:19:00
4   2020-10-31 16:01:00
5   2021-03-13 18:01:00**
6   2021-07-13 18:04:20
8   2021-07-13 18:09:46
```

The highlighted values were off by an hour. Daylight transition happened on `2019-11-03`,`2020-03-08`,`2020-11-01` and `2021-03-14`. The data looks proper before 10 hours of daylight transition and after the transition is complete (at 2:00 AM).

The ongoing replication process tried to insert the data in PST Time zone in Sql server

So, we changed our parameter on the Source and tried the below Extra connection Attribute.

```
initstmt = set time_zone = 'US/Pacific'
```

This gave us different issue. The full load on the Target inserted all the records properly.

Source:

```
id  Created_at
1   2021-07-13 18:01:48
**2 2019-11-02 18:23:00
2   2020-03-07 16:19:00
4   2020-10-31 17:01:00
5   2021-03-13 17:01:00**
6   2021-07-13 18:04:20
8   2021-07-13 18:09:46
```

Target:

```
id  Created_at
1   2021-07-13 18:01:48
**2 2019-11-02 18:23:00
2   2020-03-07 16:19:00
4   2020-10-31 17:01:00
5   2021-03-13 17:01:00**
6   2021-07-13 18:04:20
8   2021-07-13 18:09:46
```

But the ongoing replication was inserting records in UTC time zone instead PST.

Source:

```
id  Created_at
1   2021-07-13 18:01:48
2   2019-11-02 18:23:00
2   2020-03-07 16:19:00
4   2020-10-31 17:01:00
5   2021-03-13 17:01:00
6   2021-07-13 18:04:20
8   2021-07-13 18:09:46
**9 2021-07-13 18:30:57**
```

Target:

```
id  Created_at
1   2021-07-13 18:01:48
2   2019-11-02 18:23:00
2   2020-03-07 16:19:00
4   2020-10-31 17:01:00
5   2021-03-13 17:01:00
6   2021-07-13 18:04:20
8   2021-07-13 18:09:46
**9 2021-07-14 01:30:57**
```

So I am not able to migrate the data properly. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Might be more appropriate to move this question to: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I moved as suggested